# Trouble Compiling glsl Shader, #version must occur first error

Tags: opengl, glsl

I am following the [WikiBooks OpenGL Tutorial # 2](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming/Modern_OpenGL_Tutorial_02)

I can't get my shader to compile, it says #version must occur first.

Here is the main.cpp code: https://gitorious.org/wikibooks-opengl/modern-tutorials/blobs/master/tut02_clean/triangle.cpp

Here is the shader utility code:https://gitorious.org/wikibooks-opengl/modern-tutorials/blobs/master/common/shader_utils.cpp

Here is the vertex shader that is causing the error: https://gitorious.org/wikibooks-opengl/modern-tutorials/blobs/master/tut02_clean/triangle.v.glsl

I can't seem to figure out why I'm getting this error, because in the shader #version *is* first.

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure that the error is showing up in reading and creating a shader? I ask because you have an error in main.cpp. You set `compile_ok` to `GL_FALSE`, then never assign to it again, then check it and exit if it's `GL_FALSE`. So you're guaranteed to always exit and print "Error in fragment shader".

Comment: Yes, I added an if-then statement from the tutorial and I get an error stating tat #version must occur before anything else. But #version does occur first!?